# Why does the function $\overline{F}([x]_R)=[F(x)]_R$ have to be unique?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My book "Elements of Set Theory" by Enderton says that

> Assume that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $A$ and that $F:A\to A$. If $F$ is compatible with $R$, then there exists a **unique** $\overline{F}:A/R\to A/R$ such that $$\overline{F}([x]_R)=[F(x)]_R$$

I don't understand this. Isn't the identity function $F=id_A$ always such a function, regardless of whatever the equivalence relation $R$ is? And considering we know more such functions exist (an example is given in the book for $R=\mod 6$ and $F:\Bbb{N}\to \Bbb{N}$ such that $f(n)=2n$), how does uniqueness hold up?

**EDIT**: Am I mixing up the uniqueness of $\overline{F}$ and $F$? Does $\overline{F}$ have to be unique, regardless of whether $F$ is unique or not?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The uniqueness is of $\overline F$. This means that there is exactly one way to "pull" the function $F$ from a function whose domain is $A$, to a function whose domain is the quotient $A/R$.

Consider the situation (which is clearly not as above) when we take $A=\{0,1,2\}$ and $R$ to be the relation whose equivalence classes are $\{0\}$ and $\{1,2\}$. Take $F$ to be $F(0)=1, F(1)=1, F(2)=0$.

Now you have two ways of lifting $F$, either decree $\overline F([1])=[0]$, which agrees with $F(2)$ or $\overline F([1])=[1]$ which agrees with $F(1)$. (Note that $F$ is not compatible with $R$, but of course to produce such an example we can't use a function which is compatible...)

The situation where $F$ is compatible with $R$ is to say, that this doesn't happen. No, there is just one way that we can lift $F$ to a function over the quotient set such that $\overline F([x])=[F(x)]$.